# Bruteforce Attack Project

Tags: c++, brute-force

I am creating a simple 'Bruteforce attack' for a project (not school related). Could someone please tell me which part of the code is wrong to get these errors.

The Code:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
//Password array
std::string passwordArray;
//Lowercare character array
std::string lower = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", 
"n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z" };
//Uppercase character array
std::string upper = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", 
"N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" };
//Digits array
std::string digits = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };

private void setupCharArray()
{
   if (ckhLower.Checked)
{
   characterArray.AddRange(lower);
}

if (chkUpper.Checked)
{
  characterArray.AddRange(upper);
}

if (chkDigits.Checked)
{
  characterArray.AddRange(digits);
}
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  brute();
}
```

so I try to compile this code using MinGW

g++ bruteforce.cpp -o bruteforce.exe

and I get these error messages

```
c:\Users\Lotty Playle\Documents>g++ bruteforce.cpp -o bruteforce.exe
bruteforce.cpp:7:66: error: in C++98 'lower' must be initialized by constructor,
not by '{...}'
bruteforce.cpp:7:66: error: could not convert '{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g
", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w
", "x", "y", "z"}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::string {aka
std::basic_string<char>}'
bruteforce.cpp:10:66: error: in C++98 'upper' must be initialized by constructor
, not by '{...}'
bruteforce.cpp:10:66: error: could not convert '{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "
G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "
W", "X", "Y", "Z"}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::string {ak
a std::basic_string<char>}'
bruteforce.cpp:12:73: error: in C++98 'digits' must be initialized by constructo
r, not by '{...}'
bruteforce.cpp:12:73: error: could not convert '{"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "
6", "7", "8", "9"}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::string {ak
a std::basic_string<char>}'
 bruteforce.cpp:14:1: error: expected unqualified-id before 'private'
```

If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong could they please show me.

L x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An array of strings should look like this: (with `[]`)

```
std::string lower[] = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", 
"n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z" };
```

A `std::string` of characters would look like this:

```
std::string lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

Note that using a bunch of `std::string`s to represent characters is extremely inefficient. You should use a char array, or just work with ascii arithmetic.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I didn't realize that before. :)

Comment: But note that the language definition does not require implementations to use ASCII, and some systems don't.

Comment: @PeteBecker Do you happen to know what the bruteforce.cpp:14:1: error: expected unqualified-id before 'private' mean?

Comment: @charlotteplayle - an error message that follows several others may not mean much. The previous errors may mean that the code doesn't make sense. Or even if it's otherwise valid, the compiler has to guess at a reasonable continuation, and may not have guessed right. So fix the earlier errors, and see if that fixes the later ones. That said, the `private` keyword can only be used inside a class definition, and that's not the case here. Also, it should be followed by a `:`.